# In Excel, is it possible to construct an array with formulas inside it?

Tags: excel

In Google Sheets, it's possible to create an array with formulas with in it. For example, `={SUM(1,2);SUM(3,4)}` evaluates to [a column with the numbers 3 and 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTLVB.png).

When I try the same thing in Excel, I get a formula syntax error.  Is a similar thing possible? I've also tried putting names defined with `LET` in an array, but that throws the same error.

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Excel array functionality is rudimentary compared to Google Sheet. You can't combine arrays together with a expression in Excel like you can in Google Sheets. I end up using helper sheets in Excel that can be done with one expression in Google Sheets.

Comment: I assume this is a simplified transaction, can you give us a real life example of what you are trying to do?  Maybe there is something we can suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CHOOSE` function to combine formulas in array:

```
=CHOOSE({1;2},SUM(1,2),SUM(3,4))
```

[image]

formula works for O365, for earlier versions select desired count of cells and enter formula in first cell as array formula (with CSE).